# C++ regex_replace not substituting Latex like expression

Tags: c++, regex

Looks like `regex_replace` is only replacing the left parenthesis. And that too is not without a backslash:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  string text = "\\left( 0 + 1 \\right)";
  text = regex_replace(text, regex("\\left\\("), "(");
  text = regex_replace(text, regex("\\right\\)"), ")");
  cout << text;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
\( 0 + 1 \right)
```

The expected output is:

```
( 0 + 1 )
```

Comment: It appears you want to replace `"\\left( 0 + 1 \\right)"` with `"( 0 + 1 )"`. You can do that by replacing matches of the following regex with empty strings: `.+(?=\()|[^ ]+(?=\))`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cu9rnx/1). The regex reads, "match one or more characters that are followed by a left parenthesis, or (`|`) match one or more characters other than spaces that are followed by a right parenthesis. `(?=\()` and `(?=\))` are positive lookaheads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `\\\\` is required instead of `\\`. And also for round braces, I used `[(]` and `[)]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  string text = "\\left( 0 + 1 \\right)";
  text = regex_replace(text, regex("\\\\left[(]"), "(");
  cout << text << endl;
  text = regex_replace(text, regex("\\\\right[)]"), ")");
  cout << text;
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/51fhvxYjT

Comment: This is a case in which raw string literals may help readability

Comment: @MatG, sorry I didn't understood your comment. Are you by chance asking a question?

Comment: @kiner_shah: See [string_literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) (6). i.e. `string text = R"(\left( 0 + 1 \right))"; text = regex_replace(text, regex(R"(\\left\()"), "(");`

Comment: Thanks Jarod42 and MatG, this was very helpful info and I learnt something new today :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to avoid issues with escaping special regex metacharacters inside regex patterns. As, in a regex, you need two literal backslashes to match a literal backslash char, in a regular string literal you have to use four backslashes, but just two in a raw string literal. `"\\\\"` = `R"(\\)"`.

Here, you can use a single call to `regex_replace`:

```cpp
text = regex_replace(text, regex(R"(\\(left(?=\()|right(?=\))))"), "");
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/jyuwnl):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  string text = "\\left( 0 + 1 \\right)";
  text = regex_replace(text, regex(R"(\\(left(?=\()|right(?=\))))"), "");
  cout << text;
  return 0;
}
// => ( 0 + 1 )
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JKa3VS/1). *Details*:

- `\\` - a `\` char
- `(` - start of a capturing group:

  - `left(?=\()` - `left` that has a `(` char immediately on the right
  - `|` - or
  - `right(?=\))` - `right` that has a `)` char immediately on the right
- `)`